# VS Web Application project with no framework/DLL?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I want to create a JavaScript API project in Visual Studio 2013/2015/etc. I don't want any bin/obj/dll/framework as it will be pure JS. Actually, it will be using Typescript, so I do need it to be in a web project so I can get Typescript compilation, etc.

Is there any existing project template which would give me just a plain old web application with no framework attached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, at least in VS 2013 there is. New Project->Templates->TypeScript->HTML Application with TypeScript. Then, in order to avoid generating a useless dll, you have to turn off the build of the project - go to the solution Configuration Manager and uncheck Build for the project.

Comment: However, it's not true. [See the same answer and my comments, here.](http://i.imgur.com/JuAMjFc.png)

Comment: Ah, yes. And so close - the bin/obj folders still get generated. Haha. I know it's a useless question but thanks for sticking with it.